# Facebook SDK 3.0 Login for iOS apps that do not run in the background

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, uiwebview

I am in the process of implementing Facebook SDK 3.0 in my iOS app. Previously, I was able to login using a webview from within my app, but it appears that that option is no longer available in SDK 3.0.

My app does not run in the background (that is something that I am not going to change at this point). I currently launch Facebook from a view controller that is not the root controller (which is shown when the app is first launched); and I use a completion handler to finish the Facebook request when the login completes successfully.

The problem is that when the Facebook login is launched, it takes the user out of the app now; the completion handler result is never called, since the app was terminated. So the user is left on the rootController, with no results after logging in.

Is there any way to possibly login to Facebook from within the app in SDK 3.0?

If not, is there a workaround that will allow me to keep my app from running in the background?

Comment: Are you calling `[[FBSession activeSession] handleOpenURL:url];` in `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` ?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that this is not called when the user returns to the app after it is terminated, since the app delegate also implements application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: Sure but it's openURL that should be called in case facebook app opens your app

Comment: I understand that, but openURL is not getting called when Facebook opens my app

Comment: Can you add your code to do the log in and the part in delegate?

Comment: I can, but I'm not sure that would be helpful, as I do login successfully and return to the proper view controller when the app is set to run in the background. So I don't think there is a problem with the login code. The problem seems to be that openURL is not called when opening the app after termination when it is not running in the background. I also just found that launch options DOES have a UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey which gives me a URL... so now, is the question how to get application:openURL: sourceApplication: annotation to be called to open this URL? Does that sound right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16971/discussion-between-jpk-and-moxy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can force the login in a web view like this :

```
FBSession *mySession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:myAppID 
                                            permissions:myPermissions 
                                        urlSchemeSuffix:myUrlSchemeSuffix 
                                     tokenCacheStrategy:nil];
[FBSession setActiveSession:mySession];
[mySession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
          completionHandler:myCompletionHandler];
```